# Why am I unable to put my comments on others questions and answers?

Tags: support, comments, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Why am I unable to put my comments on others' questions and answers? This benefits me to 
discuss with others on the answers which are helpful to me.

Comment: You need to earn reputation in order to do that -- Check out the badges section

Comment: You have to be much more specific than that - what have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: @sscirrus I have seen an answer which is not clear to me. So I thought to put comment on his post to make it clear. But I was not able to see comment link under the answer post.

Comment: @RPM I checked in badges section. I earned commentator badge and it shows 'left 10 comments'

Comment: @Samrat If it is not your question or answer (or an answer to your question), you need 50 reputation points to comment.  See your http://stackoverflow.com/privileges page for your progress.

Comment: @jonsca Thanks jonsca. I'll do my best to get more reputation points :)

Comment: @Samrat See [this Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for further details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have a reputation score of 1 on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727722/samrat), which means that the questions and answers you've posted on the site so far have failed to receive any upvotes from other users.

Reputation is a rough measure of the quality of your contributions to the site, and thus indicates how much the community trusts you. As you gain reputation, you begin to accrue [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges). One of these privileges is the ability to [comment on questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

You will not be able to comment on other people's posts until you have earned **50 reputation**. The ability to posts comments on other people's posts is a *privilege*, and one that we unfortunately cannot unlock for new users in order to keep down noise on the site. New users also don't always understand the purpose of comments. Before you earn the privilege, we hope that you see how other users are using the comment feature and follow their example. Specifically, comments are intended for:

- providing feedback on posts
- adding relevant (but minor!) information to posts
- asking for clarification or corrections
- brief discussion on a post's contents with other members of the community

  For everything else, you should post an answer or edit your original post.

You say in your question that you might want to use comments to:

> discuss with others on the answers which are helpful to me

but remember that leaving "thank you" or "this really helped me" comments is **strongly discouraged** here. Instead, you should vote up the post you found helpful. (However, this does [require 15 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up).)

Finally, it's worth noting that *anyone* (regardless of reputation) is able to comment on their *own* posts, and even on the answers that other people provide to their *own* questions.